# I'm having hard times mounting a PlayStation 4 hard drive, need some help!

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fdisk

When I run the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I get the following message about the hard drive I want to mount to my system:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C6885C4B-5081-11E9-851B-2CCC4478E077

Dispositivo     Start      Fine   Settori   Size Tipo
/dev/sdc1   958652416 959700991   1048576   512M sconosciuto
/dev/sdc3   959700992 961798143   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc5   961798144 961830911     32768    16M sconosciuto
/dev/sdc7   961830912 962093055    262144   128M sconosciuto
/dev/sdc9   935583744 937680895   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc10  933486592 935583743   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc11  939778048 941875199   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc12  937680896 939778047   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc13  916709376 933486591  16777216     8G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc17       2048   2099199   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc19  941875200 958652415  16777216     8G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc25  964190208 976773119  12582912     6G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc27   35653632 916709375 881055744 420,1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc29  962093056 964190207   2097152     1G sconosciuto
/dev/sdc31    2099200  35653631  33554432    16G sconosciuto

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Where "sconosciuto" means "unknown" in my language. I'm interested in mounting the main partition of the hard drive, which appears to be the /dev/sdc27 running the following two commands:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk
sudo mount /dev/sdc27 /mnt/disk
```

But of course it doesn't let me mount the hard drive, giving me the error:

```
mount: /mnt/disk: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc27,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I don't know if this information might come in handy but its file system should be one among FAT32 and exFAT (not sure which)

Comment: Is the `exfat-fuse` package installed on your (Ubuntu) system?

Comment: @steeldriver: yes it is

Comment: `sudo file -s /dev/sdc27` will (hopefully) tell you what type of filesystem it is.

Comment: (Also, if you put `LC_ALL=C` in front of you command, it'll usually force that one command to output in English: `LC_ALL=C sudo fdisk -l` ought to get you English output. Useful for pasting.)

Comment: @derobert That command returns Just: data

Comment: Hmm... where did this disk come from?

Comment: @derobert It's from the PS4 of a friend, he wanted to recover some saved data from a game. It uses FAT32 or exFAT filesystem.

Comment: PS4 wiki says it's Psydo File System.  Hence hard times indeed, trying to mount this sucker. https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/PFS

Comment: @steve Any idea of how could I manage to?

Comment: [this repo](https://github.com/maxton/LibOrbisPkg#pkgtool) Refers to "PFS image" but not sure if this would be the same as a filesystem image  (for example one created from your disk with `dd`).

Answer (score 0):

PS4 wiki says it's *Psydo File System*. https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/PFS

The PS4 wiki references utilities to extract files from a Psydo File System, but offers no means to mount it.  It would appear to be a non-trivial exercise, retrieving these saved game files for your friend.

https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/Files_on_the_PS4#Partitions